# Summarize changes (insertions and deletions) in Git

Tags: git

I want to look at how my code base has grown over time. GitHub has a nice `+/-` display along the list of checkins which gives a sense of this. Is there something similar I can use with my Google Code hosted repo or offline?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the usage of tools specific to software development. These questions belong on Stack Overflow, but this question is too old to migrate.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Answer (score 105, accepted):

There are a few options natively in Git to get data about the changes.

`git log --stat` will show the amount each file was changed.

`git whatchanged` gives some detail into the files that were modified.

`git diff --stat <sha1> <sha2>` gives the files and the amount of changes between two commits.

There are many other blogs that give various formatted logs.  A google search can point you at these.  Also doing `git log --help` will give the various options for formatting the history of your repo.  Git has the ability to give you quite a bit of data through the various command line `log` options (filtering by author, file, etc).

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks. Now I also see `--numstat` provides a less sugary but clean alternative format.

Comment: `--shortstat` will just print out the totals.

Comment: keep in mind that `git diff --stat <sha1> <sha2>` doesn't includes insertions and deletions in `<sha1>`, so you would have to put the `sha` of commit just before `<sha1>` to includes `<sha1>`

Answer (score 26):

If you know the commits you would like to compare, you could try using [the `git diff` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) with the `--stat` argument. It gives output like this:

```
$ git diff --stat HEAD^ HEAD
_layouts/default.html |    1 -
_sass/_variables.scss |    2 +-
_sass/main.scss       |   42 +++++++++++++++---------------------------
3 files changed, 16 insertions(+), 29 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Always love an example that works for most cases (HEAD - 1) instead of an abstraction. Thanks Mike!